# Is this equivalent to RH - Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

$$\pi = 3\prod_{\zeta(1/2+it) = 0}\frac{9+4t^2}{1+4t^2}\iff\text{RH is true}.$$

Comment: I'd suggest you expand on this a bit, tell us your reasoning for asking the question, what you mean by $\mathfrak{I}(r)$, why you believe or disbelieve it, etc.

Comment: ℑ(r) denotes the imaginary part. If RH is true then the product equals Pi.
My question relates to whether it is true vice versa.
That is, if the product is equal to Pi then and RH is true. r is a zeta zero.

Comment: Despite appearances, this question makes sense (and the equivalence is  probably correct).  But all it amounts to is writing down the Hadamard formula for the completed Riemann $\xi$ function evaluated at $2$.  The product is presumably over positive ordinates $t$.

Comment: Well if RH is not true if suffices to replace $t$ by $-i(\rho-1/2)$ so it is not a very useful criterion.

Comment: @Lucia With $\beta$ the zeros on $\Re(s) = 1/2$ of $F(s)=\alpha L(s,\chi_5)+\overline{\alpha} L(s,\overline{\chi_5})$, can we expect the distribution $\sum_{\beta} \delta(u-\Im( \beta))$ to have some useful properties and interpretation ? (it is the discrete part of the Fourier transform of the coefficients of $\frac{F'(s+1/2)}{F(s+1/2)}$)

Comment: Posted a year ago here: [Riemann Hypothesis and Prime summation](//math.stackexchange.com/q/2066915)

Comment: Next time, please ask a question. In the above example, you could have asked: is this statement true and has it been asked before?

Comment: BTW I upvoted the question, despite my criticism.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, this is equivalent to RH (but not in any significant way).  Recall the completed Riemann $\xi$-function 
$$ 
\xi(s) = s(s-1) \pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s), 
$$ 
which, by Hadamard's factorization formula can be written as
$$ 
e^{A+Bs} \prod_{\rho}\Big(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\Big) e^{s/\rho},  
$$ 
where the product is over all non-trivial zeros $\rho$ of $\zeta(s)$.
Now one can check that $A=0$ (plug in $s=0$) and that $B= -\sum_{\rho}\text{Re }(1/\rho)$.  It follows that 
$$ 
|\xi(s)| = \prod_{\rho: \text{Im}(\rho) >0} \Big| \frac{s-\rho}{\rho}\Big|^2,
$$ 
by grouping complex conjugate zeros (and the product now converges). Now evaluate this at $s=2$: thus 
$$ 
\xi(2) =2 \times 1 \times \pi^{-1} \times \Gamma(1) \times \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi}{3} 
$$ 
equals 
$$ 
\prod_{\rho: \text{Im}(\rho) >0} \Big| \frac{2-\rho}{\rho}\Big|^2. 
$$

Split the product over zeros into two factors: the first one from zeros on the critical line, and the second one over zeros not on the critical line (if any).  The first factor is simply 
$$
\prod_{\substack{\rho = 1/2 +i\gamma \\ \gamma >0}} \frac{(3/2)^2+\gamma^2}{(1/2)^2 +\gamma^2} = \prod_{\substack{\rho = 1/2 +i\gamma \\ \gamma >0}} \frac{9+4\gamma^2}{1+4\gamma^2}.
$$ 
If RH is true then the second factor is $1$.  If RH is false, then note that the contribution of the zeros $\beta+i\gamma$ and $1-\beta+i\gamma$ together to the second product is 
$$ 
\frac{(2-\beta)^2+\gamma^2}{\beta^2+\gamma^2} \frac{(1+\beta)^2+\gamma^2}{(1-\beta)^2 +\gamma^2} > 1;
$$ 
(both factors are $\ge 1$ since $0\le \beta \le 1$, and at least one of them must be strictly larger than $1$).

There's a little bit more fun to be had with this problem.  It can be used to show easily that if $\gamma_0$ is the first ordinate of a zero (not necessarily on the critical line) of $\zeta(s)$ then 
$$
\frac{\pi}{3} \ge \frac{9+4\gamma_0^2}{1+4\gamma_0^2}, 
$$ 
and since $\pi$ is so close to $3$, one can extract from this the fairly good bound that $\gamma_0 \ge 6.49\ldots$.  This general idea is of course well known, but I thought this particular choice was pretty!

Comment: I thought $\xi(2)=\pi/6.$

Comment: @AntonioHernándezMaquívar it seems the formula for $\xi(s)$ at the start is missing a factor of $\frac12$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function), which would fix the problem you mention.

Answer (score -2):

I begin by prefacing I have no formal mathematics education.

This answer mirrors the answer given by Lucia. We have
$$
\frac{\pi}{6}=\xi(2)=\frac{1}{2}\prod_{\rho}\left(1-\frac{2}{\rho} \right).\label{a}\tag{1}
$$
Here the product is taken over the roots of $\xi,$ and should be done so over conjugate pairs i.e., the factors for a pair of zeroes of the form $\rho$ and $1−\rho$ should be grouped together.  After multiplying the LHS and RHS of $\ref{a}$ by $2$, we get:
$$
\frac{\pi}{3}=\prod_{\rho}\left(1-\frac{2}{\rho} \right).
$$
Now, assume Riemann's hypothesis, that is all non trivial zeros have real part equal to $\frac{1}{2}.$ Writing $\rho=\frac{1}{2}+i\gamma$ and $\rho^*=\frac{1}{2}-i\gamma,$ leads to:
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{3} &=\prod_{\gamma >0}\left(1-\frac{2}{1/2+i\gamma} \right)\left(1-\frac{2}{1/2-i\gamma} \right)\\
&=\prod_{\gamma >0}\frac{(-3+2i\gamma)(-3-2i\gamma)}{(1+2i\gamma)(1-2i\gamma)}\\
&=\prod_{\gamma >0}\frac{4\gamma^2+9}{4\gamma^2+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Your final line of equations should presumably have the product indexed by $\gamma$ with positive real part, and so the last equation (to the single fraction involving $\gamma$) does not hold.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - I have corrected that. Thank you.

Comment: You are still using the same notation $\prod_{\rho}$ for the whole set of zeroes and then for half of it without telling.

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier I have attempted to make my argument more precise.